# SQL Server : how to dump/extract each row to separate file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a business requirement to take a table with columns `PrimaryKey, A, B, C, D, E` and dump each to a file such as:

```
filename:  Primarykey.txt
(row 1) A
(row 2) B
(row 3) C
```

etc.

Is there a good way to do this with SQL Server 2008 or should I write a C# program using a datatable? The table I am using has about 200k rows in it.

Thanks

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352104/create-multiple-flat-file-from-running-same-query-with-different-criteria

Comment: might be a better solution here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic530435-147-1.aspx

Comment: Writing into a file is also described here http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_SQLWrFile/

Comment: I don't have SSIS installed at the moment.  I have SQL 2012 dev edition though, I can always get it.  Right now I am thinking I can do this in C# faster/better, but it's a really good project for learning SSIS (which I don't know anything about).  Thanks for everyone's comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links below contain some previous posts and another link to a possible solution using SSIS.

You might have to play around until you get what you want.

Good luck.

[Some clues here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352104/create-multiple-flat-file-from-running-same-query-with-different-criteria)

or 
[SQL Server Forums - Create multiple files from SSIS](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=127561)

Answer (score 1):

#### Using xp_cmdshell

If xp_cmdshell is permitted, you might be able to use something like this:

```
declare @path varchar(200)
declare @schema varchar(100)
declare @pk varchar(100)
declare @sql varchar(2000)
declare @cmd varchar(2500)
set @path = 'C:\your\file\path\'
declare rowz cursor for (select PrimaryKey from TableA)
open rowz
fetch next from rowz into @pk
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @sql = 'select A, B, C, D, E from TableA where PrimaryKey = ''' + @pk + ''''
    set @cmd = 'bcp "' + @sql + '" queryout "' + @path + @pk + '.txt" -T -c -t\n'
    exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
    fetch next from rowz into @item
end
close rowz
deallocate rowz
```

---

#### Using sqlcmd

Alternately, you can create a series of statements to run through `sqlcmd` to create the separate files.

First, create a temporary table and add some boilerplate entries:

```
create table #temp (tkey int, things varchar(max))
insert into #temp (tkey, things) values (0, 'SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO'),(2, ':out stdout')
```

Then, fill the temporary table with the queries that we need:

```
declare @dir varchar(250)
declare @sql varchar(5000)
declare @cmd varchar(5500)
declare @schema varchar(100)
declare @pk varchar(100)
set @schema = 'YourSchema'
declare rowz cursor for (select PrimaryKey from "YourSchema"..TableA)
open rowz
fetch next from rowz into @pk
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @dir = '"C:\your\file\path\'+@pk+'.txt"'
    set @sql = '
SELECT A +''
''+ B +''
''+ C +''
''+ D +''
''+ E
FROM "'+@schema+'"..TableA where PrimaryKey = '+@pk
    set @cmd = ':out '+@dir+@sql+'
GO'
    insert into #temp (tkey,things) values (1, @cmd)
    fetch next from rowz into @pk
end
close rowz
deallocate rowz
```

Next, query the temporary table to get the generated queries:

```
select things from #temp order by tkey
```

Finally, copy the results to a file and send this file as input to `sqlcmd.exe` at the command prompt with the parameter `-h -1`:

```sh
C:\your\file\path>sqlcmd -h -1 -S YourServer -i "script.sql"
```